# How to increase timeout on AWS

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services

How can I configure a bootstrap action to increase the timeout for my custom jar on AWS?

The error, I am getting now is:

```
Task attempt failed to report status for 600 seconds. Killing!
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the following in the configuration : mapreduce.task.timeout . It is in milliseconds and default value is 600000 i.e. 600 seconds. You can increase it.

Refer below link:
[Configuration](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)